# One user with offensive username

Tags: support, account

What can i do if i see a user using an username offensive for my religion? because this is community used by differents people from many places of the world

Comment: While I sympathise... You can't expect something so delicate as religion to be dealt with a two sentence meta question... If anything this post should be removed and you should ask the company for a formal stance if it is a critical issue for you. Not the community.

Comment: Offensive usernames are a subject for meta.stackexchange because the policy is for all SE sites.  Go there and search for "offensive usernames" to see what the guidelines are.

Comment: Is it hate speech ("Kill_the_[insert group]" or "[insert group]_burn_in_hell") or is it, well, unfunny humor?  Because the former has an actual flag category, and might therefore be taken more seriously than the latter.

Answer (score 12):

Bring your sense of humor and think about what you said: This is an international community, meaning many people won't share your view of what's offensive.

If you really can't do this, please [contact](https://meta.serverfault.com/contact) the admin team, moderators can't do anything about it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117596/possibly-offensive-usernames